# VBA- how to remove only SECOND occurrence of a character (in each cell of a Word doc table)

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

(I have avidly searched the forum, but the only similar 'replace' questions I could find were related to Python, Java etc, and not VBA)

- I have a table within a MS Word (2010) document (it has two columns but only the second column has text in)
- Some cells in the second column have one line of text and NO paragraph mark
- Other cells in the second column have two lines of text and TWO paragraph marks (^p)
- There is no regular pattern between these two types of cells
- Where there is a **second** paragraph mark, this always occurs directly before the end-of-cell marker

I really need a macro to remove (replace with " ") this **second** (=final) paragraph mark from each cell where it occurs, but to ignore any first paragraph marks within the cells.

I would be extremely grateful if someone out there has the time and inclination to help me with this macro.  As you might have guessed I have little experience in VBA despite attempting to give myself a crash course: I am more used to recording macros which is not an option in this more intricate case.

My hopes were raised when Google found me this- which looks like it could be adaptable http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=334; but I have no idea how to tweak it to only replace a SECOND (/final) occurrence of ^p.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Dim tbl As Table
Dim c As Cell


For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
    For Each c In tbl.Columns(2).Cells
        'The end of a cell without a carriage return is vbCr & Chr(7)
        If Right(c.Range.Text, 3) = vbCr & vbCr & Chr(7) Then
            c.Range.Text = Mid(c.Range.Text, 1, Len(c.Range.Text) - 3) & Chr(7)
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: First and foremost- THANK YOU!  I am so much closer now than yesterday.  The problem now is that I am losing all formatting in the macro-ed cells (the formatting varies between different lines of the same cell), and I realise this is because we are removing the end-of-cell marker.  Is there anyway, instead of removing the final 3 characters [Len(c.Range.Text) **- 3**], we can remove the **third-to-last** character only?  (length of cell text varies...)  Many thanks again.  (I have researched the forum/google and cannot find anything solid myself.)